# How do I decrease the scale of an instanced node or scene?

Tags: godot

I'm trying to decrease size of instanced `RigidBody2D` scene, through code. With `scale()`, I'm trying to decrease the size of the image/sprite that's attached to the `RigidBody2D`. The problem is, it's not working.

No matter how much I try to scale down, the size of the blood drop circle remains the same.

---

```
const blood_druple_scn = preload("res://Scenes/blood.tscn")

func spawnBlood():
    var newBlood = Blood_druple_scn.instance()

    rotationAdd = rotationAdd + 30

    if(switchBloodSize == 0):
        set_scale(Vector2(2,1)) //This part is my problem
        print("blood size: ", newBlood.get_scale())
        add_child(newBlood)
        switchBloodSize = 1

    elif(switchBloodSize == 1):
        newBlood.scale(Vector2(0.5,0.5)) //This part is my problem
        print("Blood size: ", newBlood.get_scale())
        add_child(newBlood)
        switchBloodSize = 0

    newBlood.set_pos(Vector2(100,100))
    rotate(rotationAdd)
```

As you can see, I have two different `if` conditions, each with a different `scale()` and size. Sadly, both remain the same size. The strange part is that it does display the scale values as been altered, yet the `newBlood` instance is not visually changing. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

According to this issue https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/179 you cannot change rigid bodies scale. What is suggested is to scale your nodes instead, for example:

```
var sprite = newBlood.get_node("./Sprite")
sprite.scale(Vector2(0.5,0.5))
```

This "limitation" only occurs in Rigid and Character modes, by the way.